# JavaScript alternative to CSS Regions

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Adobe's proposed CSS region flow (http://html.adobe.com/webplatform/layout/regions/) looks great but is not yet widely adopted (http://html.adobe.com/webplatform/layout/regions/browser-support/ and http://caniuse.com/css-regions).

Can something similar be achieved with a script approach? Something robust that will break appropriately to ensure text and inline images won't get cropped and instead be pushed to the next available region.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=css+regions+polyfill

Comment: Thanks, should have thought of searching for a polyfill!